# Проблема с setup:upgrade в случае cмонтированого каталога pub/media

Tags: linux, magento

Есть рабочий сервер c установленной magento community-edition 2.1.9. Размер каталога pub/media 324GB. Есть тестовый сервер. Для того что бы на тестовом сервере работали картинки было решено cмонтировать следующие каталоги с рабочего режиме ro:
pub/media/catalog/product/1
pub/media/catalog/product/2
...
pub/media/catalog/product/9
Сервера находятся в разных странах. После того как папки были cмонтированы возникла проблема при выполнении на тестовом сервере команды
`php -d memory_limit=2G bin/magento setup:upgrade`.

> DDL cache cleared successfully
>
> Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.

Увеличение memory_limit до 4G проблему не решает. Если работать с локальным каталогом pub/media то проблем нету. Вопрос в том как сделать так что бы и картинки работали и setup:upgrade?
Сразу скажу, что перенести все картинки не вариант, так как на тестовом сервере столько места нету.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина проблемы была в том, что при `setup:upgrade` рекурсивно проверяется право записи на ряд директорий, в том числе и media. Поскольку media была смонтирована в режиме ro, то процесс зависал и выжирал при этом всю выделенную ему память. Исключили media из проверки и всё заработало.